# Qt + OpenCV grayscale error

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I been trying to make a simple interface for an image processing task using OpenCV with C++ using Qt for the GUI.
I'm able to load the image through the GUI but when I press the pushbutton_3,
to convert the image to grayscale gives an error regarding OpenCV.
I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Can some one give me a help?

Please see below the files:

```
//mainwindow.h

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/types_c.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();




private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    //Images variables
    cv::Mat image_Idl;
    cv::Mat image_Lit;
    cv::Mat image_Idl_G;
    cv::Mat image_Lit_G;
    double threshHold;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/types_c.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QSlider>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->horizontalSlider->setRange(0,255);
    ui->spinBox->setRange(0,255);

    connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),ui->spinBox,SLOT(setValue(int)));
    connect(ui->spinBox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),ui->horizontalSlider,SLOT(setValue(int)));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Load Lit Image"),".",tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)"));
    image_Lit = cv::imread(fileName.toAscii().data());
    cv::namedWindow("Lit Image");
    cv::imshow("Lit Image", image_Lit);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Load Lit Image"),".",tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)"));
    image_Idl = cv::imread(fileName.toAscii().data());
    cv::namedWindow("Ideal Lit");
    cv::imshow("Ideal Lit", image_Idl);

}






void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    //Converstions


    //Convert Lit to gray



        cv::cvtColor(image_Lit, image_Lit_G,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    //Convert Ideal gray


        cv::cvtColor(image_Idl, image_Idl_G,CV_RGB2GRAY);


      //Threshold the Images to a designated value
                // Lit

        threshHold = ui->horizontalSlider->value();

          cv::threshold(image_Lit_G,image_Lit_G, threshHold,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
          cv::namedWindow("Gray Scaled Image");
          cv::imshow("Gray Scaled Image", image_Lit_G);


}
```

Error from the compiler:

Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file C:\OpenCV\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 2834
The program has unexpectedly finished.

Pop up window error:

Microsoft Visual C++

This application as requested to terminate in an unusual way.

Comment: What error do you get? It's going to be near impossible to guess from only your header file (which I do not believe has anything at all to do with the problem).

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific that "gives an error"? The code you're providing also is not enough to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Could you post the part of the code that converts the image from OpenCV format to Qt imge (or whatever you are using to show the image in Qt)?

Comment: Appologies guys I just noticed that my copy paste wasn't  succefull. I'm editing and upadting with the missing information.

Comment: Just update. Unfortunately the system does not allow me to post images...

Comment: make sure that the image_Lit and imageIdl are RGB before passing this images to the cvtColor function. you can do that by verifying the number of channels of the image). You get an assertion because the cvtColor is expecting the input image to have 3 or 4 components and this condition is not satisfied.

Comment: First, check the number of channels for both your images, the error must be there as @alinoz points out. And try using CV_BGR2GRAY instead of CV_RGB2GRAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recompiled the above program after updating my windows7 machine and astonishing it worked!
Its really weird... I didn't made any changes to the program (at least I can't remenber doing anythin significantly different) but after reinstalling comodo firewal it worked.....
Thanks guys, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "iostream"
#include "cv.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("C:\\lena.jpg");
    cvtColor(image,image,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    imshow("test",image);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

above code(console app in Qt..) is working....it shows a gray image...try to include the **cv.h** file...

Comment: Yes the above code works. I made the inteire program in plain c++ and works. The problem Im having is to add GUI that executes the functions I did in plain coding. I creat a button (pushbutton_3) to execute  several functions such as transform the image to grayscale,threshold find the contours etc. The problem is that when I press the button it gives error in the first operation that in this case is to convert the image to grayscale.

Comment: did u try the C interface with IplImage ?

Comment: I don't know the C interface.

Comment: Hi guys with the exception of the C interface I have tried all your suggestions and failed :(.
Unfortunately I don't have more rights to post an image of the GUI as I don't have enough right to do so. I have posted all the code I made.